# What is the default timeout for URL in Java? How does this affect url.openStream()?

Tags: java, url, default

What is the default timeout for `URL` in Java?
How does this affect url.openStream()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of timeouts: `connection timeout` and `read timeout`.
Default will be `-1 (infinity)` for connection timeout and read timeout.

`openStream()` makes connection and provides input stream so `openStream()` will have impact from connection timeout and read timeout.

The following code in JDK explains this:

```
package sun.net

public class NetworkClient {
    /* Default value of read timeout, if not specified (infinity) */
    public static final int DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT = -1;

    /* Default value of connect timeout, if not specified (infinity) */
    public static final int DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = -1;
    ...
}
```